Disable ScrollView until Drag Threshold is passed all in one gesture
i am trying to implement a custom gesture on this view that makes it so that only when a certain drag threshold is passed, does the underlying scrollview receive the drag touch events and begin scrolling all in one gesture. trying to mimic what i assume to be the gesture logic in the new ios 18 photos app
in my head i am envisioning it like the gesture blocks touch events from passing through until a certain threshold then it allows recognizing simultaneously with

enum DragState {
    case dragging
    case draggedUp
    case draggedDown
    case idle
}

struct Home: View {
    // MARK: - Environment Variables

    @Environment(\.viewSize) private var viewSize
    @Environment(\.safeAreaInsets) private var safeAreaInsets
    @EnvironmentObject private var windowState: UIState

    // MARK: - State Variables

    @State var isExpanded = false
    @State var dragState: DragState = .idle

    @State var scrollOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var topScrollOffset: CGFloat = 0

    @State var bottomOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var topOffset: CGFloat = 0

    // MARK: - Constants

    let maxTranslation: CGFloat = 124

    var body: some View {
        let offset: CGFloat = viewSize.height * 0.4

        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 120), spacing: 4)], spacing: 4) {
                        ForEach(1 ... 50, id: \.self) { _ in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color(.systemGray5))
                                .frame(height: 120)
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(y: topOffset)
                }
                .onScrollGeometryChange(for: CGFloat.self, of: {
                    /// This will be zero when the content is placed at the bottom
                    $0.contentOffset.y - $0.contentSize.height + $0.containerSize.height
                }, action: { oldValue, newValue in
                    guard oldValue != newValue else { return }
                    topScrollOffset = newValue

                    if isExpanded, newValue >= 0 {
                        //
                    }
                })
                .scrollClipDisabled()
                .defaultScrollAnchor(.bottom)
                .frame(height: viewSize.height)
                .border(.blue, width: 2)

                VStack(spacing: 4) {
                    ForEach(1 ... 12, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color(.systemGray6))
                            .frame(height: 120)
                    }
                }
                .border(.red, width: 2)
                .offset(y: bottomOffset)
            }
        }
        .onScrollGeometryChange(for: CGFloat.self, of: {
            /// This will be zero when the content is placed at the bottom
            $0.contentOffset.y
        }, action: { oldValue, newValue in

            guard oldValue != newValue else { return }
            scrollOffset = newValue

            if !isExpanded, newValue <= 0 {
                //
            }

        })
        .defaultScrollAnchor(.top)
        .scrollClipDisabled()
        .frame(height: viewSize.height, alignment: .top)
        .clipped()
        .scaleEffect(0.65)
        .gesture(
            CustomGesture(isEnabled: true) { recognizer in
                let translation = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view).y
                let state = recognizer.state

                // MARK: - Gesture Began

                if state == .began {
                    dragState = .dragging
                }

                // MARK: - Gesture Changed

                if state == .changed {
                }

                // MARK: - Gesture Ended

                if state == .ended {
                }
            }
        )
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                topOffset = -offset
                bottomOffset = -offset
            }
        }
    }
}

since SwiftUI gestures don’t work simultaneously with scrollView

struct CustomGesture: UIGestureRecognizerRepresentable {
    var isEnabled: Bool
    var handle: (UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> ()

    func makeCoordinator(converter: CoordinateSpaceConverter) -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIGestureRecognizer(context: Context) -> UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        gesture.delegate = context.coordinator
        return gesture
    }

    func updateUIGestureRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer, context: Context) {
        recognizer.isEnabled = isEnabled
    }

    func handleUIGestureRecognizerAction(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer, context: Context) {
        handle(recognizer)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        func gestureRecognizer(
            _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
            shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
        ) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
    }
}

